# What are the benefits of immutability?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, immutability

I'm using React to render long scrollable list of items (+1000). I found [React Virtualized](https://bvaughn.github.io/react-virtualized/) to help me with this.

So looking at the [example here](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/blob/master/source/VirtualScroll/VirtualScroll.example.js) I should pass down the list as a prop to my item list component. What's tripping me up is that in the example the list is immutable (using [Immutable.js](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/)) which I guess makes sense since that's how the props are supposed to work - but if I want to make a change to a row item I cannot change its state since the row will be rerendered using the list, thus throwing out the state.

What I'm trying to do is to highlight a row when I click it and have it still be highlighted if I scroll out of the view and back into it again. Now if the list is not immutable I can change the object representing the row and the highlighted row will stay highlighted, but I'm not sure that's the correct way to do it. Is there a solution to this other than mutating the props?

```
class ItemsList extends React.Component {
  (...)
  render() {
    (...)    
    return(
      <div>
        <VirtualScroll
          ref='VirtualScroll'
          className={styles.VirtualScroll}
          height={virtualScrollHeight}
          overscanRowCount={overscanRowCount}
          noRowsRenderer={this._noRowsRenderer}
          rowCount={rowCount}
          rowHeight={useDynamicRowHeight ? this._getRowHeight : virtualScrollRowHeight}
          rowRenderer={this._rowRenderer}
          scrollToIndex={scrollToIndex}
          width={300}
        />
      </div>
    )
  }
  _rowRenderer ({ index }) {
    const { list } = this.props;
    const row = list[index];

    return (
      <Row index={index} />
    )
  }
}


class Row extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      highlighted: false
    };
  }

  handleClick() {
    this.setState({ highlighted: true });

    list[this.props.index].color = 'yellow';
  }

  render() {
    let color = list[this.props.index].color;

    return (
      <div 
        key={this.props.index}
        style={{ height: 20, backgroundColor: color }}
        onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}
        >
        This is row {this.props.index}
      </div>
    )
  }  
}

const list = [array of 1000+ objects];

ReactDOM.render(
  <ItemsList
    list={list} 
  />,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what the question you are asking is, as you've asked two distinct questions.

Comment: This is what it looks like if I change the state of the row: http://output.jsbin.com/hopuhuhihu

Comment: You're right it's not exactly clear...I want to highlight some rows in a list. My solution to that is to change a list I use as props in a component. I don't think I should do this, but I don't know why.

Comment: Immutability is fine, when you never want the state to change. As we live in a world where states change constantly, I feel this idea of complete code immutability is naive and unrealistic.

Comment: But a thing like if a row is highlighted or not feels like something that should be in the state of the Row component. Or maybe I could put the index of the highlighted row in the state of the ItemList component.

Comment: If a row is highlighted, then it seems logical that the state should be kept by the row component.

Answer (score 0):

If you only render let's say 10 out of your list of a 1000 at a time, then the only way to remember highlighted-flag, is to store it in the parent state, which is the list of 1000.

Without immutability, this would be something like:

```
// make a copy of the list - NB: this will not copy objects in the list
var list = this.state.list.slice();    
// so when changing object, you are directly mutating state
list[itemToChange].highlighted = true; 
// setting state will trigger re-render
this.setState({ list: list });
// but the damage is already done: 
// e.g. shouldComponentUpdate lifecycle method will fail
// will always return false, even if state did change.
```

With immutability, you would be doing something quite similar:

```
// make a copy of the list
var list = this.state.list.slice();
// make a copy of the object to update
var newObject = Object.assign({}, list[itemToChange]);
// update the object copy
newObject.highlighted = true;
// insert the new object into list copy
list[itemToChange] = newObject;
// update state with the new list
this.setState({ list : list );
```

The above only works if the object does not contain more nested objects.
I am not familiar with immutable.js, but I'm sure they have excellent methods to deal with this more appropriately.

The argument for immutability in react is that you can reliably and transparently work with state changes (also react's life-cycle methods expect them). There are numerous questions on SO with a variant of "why is nextState == this.state", with answers coming down to "not keeping state and props immutable screwed things up"